# alter sql script for postgres type "AS" does not exist

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want write postgres alter script to add one column in existing table 
i tried this script, it works fine in **ms sql server** and **oracle** too
but i am getting error in **postgres sql**

ERROR:  type "AS" does not exist
LINE 1: alter table employee add unique_colum SET (case when  ...

```
ALTER TABLE employee add unique_colum AS (case when flag = 'n' then ids else name end);
```

**flag** and **ids** are the existing **columns**, i want to add one more column called **unique_colum** 
and value of the new column from any of existing table.

Comment: An error in postgres should only be tagged postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres does not support computed columns.  You are using syntax for SQL Server in Postgres.

You can get similar functionality using a view:

```
create view v_employee as
    select e.*, (case when flag = 'n' then ids else name end) as unique_column
    from employee;
```

Comment: @RaviKumar . . . You can create a unique index on an expression in Postgres.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...you are right but the new column what i added should have different values from more than one column based on case statement...